# Why is code sometimes called "listings"?

Tags: terminology, history

When reading *Programmers at Work* (by Susan Lammers), they often refer to code as "listings". Why is that?

Comment: The question as is sounds like it belongs to english.SE instead...

Comment: She's probably referring to specific chunks of code used as examples in the text of the book. They could also be called "snippets" or "chunks" or "samples"...

Comment: "Listing" is pretty common terminology. The LaTeX package for source code is called [Listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was more common when we read code on paper - long lists of code from a line printer.

Remember the green ruled paper ... arghh the nostalgia!

[image]

Comment: Yup. Once upon a time it was fairly common practice to actually print your code out on paper, as laughable as that seems today.

Comment: @Adam Crossland - Why laughlable? When I'm working on an algorithm (or something that reasonably fits within a page or two) I usually print it out. Better than staring at it on screen watching where you missed that one index. ... Although, I grant it's not so common approach anymore.

Comment: @Rook: I thought of it as being laughable largely because the reason that *I* did it back in the days that I was working on PDP-11s and later VAXen was that it was sometimes the only way to get a handle on a non-trivial bit of code. The displays were 80 characters across and 24 lines down, and that just wasn't a whole lot of code. Today, I can rotate my widescreen monitor 90 degrees, change fonts and see *a whole bunch of code at one time.*

Comment: I remember those days.  Dot matrix and all churning out MSBasic and RMCobol.  Ahaaa.

Comment: A long time ago, in a shop not really far away, the codebase was in a primitive version control system (based on virtual punch card decks), and also printed out and sitting in bindings (this was before we all had terminals).  We had a "lock to edit" process that consisted of writing "See <name> before changing" on the program listing.  I prefer local computers with two monitors and Subversion, on the whole.

Comment: Don't forget, in those days we didn't have IDEs, just basic text editors.  If you needed to change a variable name, you needed to print a cross-reference listing so you could see every place it was used.  Or else run through the edit-compile loop a dozen or so times until you stopped getting `UNRECOGNIZED SYMBOL 'BAZ' IN ASSIGNMENT STATEMENT AT LINE 00000123`.

Comment: @David - there's a lot to be said for a copy on paper. I've never accidentally pulled instead of pushed to a printer!

Comment: @Martin Beckett - On the other hand, 'twas quite a lot of merging even back then!

Comment: @Adam It is less common in OO programming than procedural. I maintaned a legacy C program, and found paper listing much easier to follow than paging in a window (some of the critical methods were hundreds of lines long)

Answer (score 4):

The term dates back to a time when programs were stored on eighty-column Hollerith-encoded punch cards.  I am old enough to remember those days. All of my early programs where entered via a keypunch machine and debugged via printed compiler output "listings."

As an aside: early terminals were eighty columns wide because that line size mapped well to "card image" data.  Most of the early on-line systems were merely data collection and presentation subsystems for card-image batch systems.  This information processing model was known as "deferred batch."

Answer (score 3):

It refers to printed out code.

Actually, in a food manufacturer that I've been to in the last few years, they still print out all code from their PLC's and keep them in hanging files.  Part of the procedure for updating a program always involves updating the paper copies.

Maintenance people regularly come in and pull a binder to look at it.  In some ways it's handy, especially when you can look at it on big plots (it's a graphical programming language) rather than on a tiny screen.

Answer (score 3):

In old line oriented basic system there was an interpreter command `LIST` to show the programmcode

So `LIST` produces a source code `LIST`-ing

Comment: Not only that, but in these old languages (mostly BASIC), lines of code were *numbered* (numbers = labels), so a program was really an ordered *list* of instructions, like a shopping list.